# Итератор в цикле с#

Tags: c#, .net

Столкнулся с небольшим недопониманием. Почему на шестой итерации цикла в итератор попадает мусор (-5.55111..)? А должен быть 0.
Код программы:

```
using System;
namespace frost1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            double a, b, h;
            Console.WriteLine("Input please the A variable (bottom):");
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Input please the B variable (top):");
            b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Input please the H (step) variable:");
            h = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if (a >= b) Console.WriteLine("Wrong interval... Repeat the input");
            else
            {
                double res = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("x\t\t\ty");
                for (double i = a; i <= b; i+=h)
                {
                    res = Math.Pow(i, 2) - Math.Sin(Math.Pow(i,4));
                    Console.WriteLine(i+"\t\t\t"+res);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Решил проблему использованием типа decimal.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что у вас не `-5.55111`, а `-0.0000000000000000555111`.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что нужно округлять. Виной тому - формат представления чисел с плавающей точкой в компьютере. Почитать можно [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/).

В вашем случае проблемы с точностью представления значения около нуля. Можно попробовать так:

```
...
for (double i = a; i <= b; i+=h)
{
    res = Math.Pow(i, 2) - Math.Sin(Math.Pow(i,4));
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(i, 1)+"\t\t\t"+Math.Round(res, 4));
}
```